# Can you prevent an interface property whose type is function being implemented as a method in a Class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**Background**

Given the following interface

```
interface MyInterface<I, O> {
    execute: (input: I) => O
}
```

The TS compiler is then happy with either of the following implementations of `MyInterface`:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface<string, number> {

    execute = (input: string): number => 1; 
}
```

Or

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface<string, number> {

    execute(input: string): number {
        return 1;
    } 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5ryQHkwBpkB5APmQG8BYAKGUeQgA8IEBXSALmQApQABy69MASmQBeSqXoBfevQQAbOAGc1adAGFVGgIzJgAW0HKIxiOE0ZskWIgj41YKKADmJEB2MAjaJS0dPRMzGyckFL8QiLILm4g7mK83n7QUpT6ANzI8op0Kuo2OnpqAExGpuaW1lp2uI7Orh5ePv5QgfmhrOxcEAIgwmC88R7JyKnt1CGhTFAQYBxQIMjZM4xyuXQKwbsA9AeHR8cnp2fnFyf5SqXIACroghAAgtMMTABucMocKJLIAAYsutkAATAD2AGVwZYwAALDx8cYPJ6vIKzJjw4BqAB0Xx+KAA1P99ECQaF5otlsgsWpge8NnldoUNPdHhAAEJvUL435RMkMsFQmELBGJACiyjU-WR7K56IxNIRuN5RJJAsVyEpSxWtPpoR2O3olxNprN5uuBVuGF0RWeoGe4K4hhMZgsVjAxXqDgIKJeJD9z06u264T6UQGQ14gdlqIy3MV2upMTAOIh0NhYvcSP1TEN+RZxVtGg5oA5TrALqq7tqthwPqcfo5AblwZBPQif2ig1iTdjnPjCoxSZWKbTwszHkl0pzIPzzOtJTtZYrVbdNU9dXreEb7OeLaeHLbgo74f+kd7e-7XOkCeHCx1EwgAHc2YekXOmTcilpi2p7SAzzls6lTrh6Xrbo0gYHi8yAAD5vpyx6hr0kTnim0ZXphcYIU2g7knMD7UiAL6IRyH6CvO36sjapRAQ6wGVqB1TgVu9g7vggbwWRMGvLhrZvO2YZod2UaIXxZH9hJeG3kOswjk+r5NhRBpflaP60XapaAauzE1pudbsVBe7cU2vHIUwp4iRewziaZcpSfhgoUkRKwkUpe4qXmanmr5fn+acBaLn+AGOlwFSuixtZYJBvp7uZgknsJ-QYeJjlyS5VKjj2qbpiKWKJLOlFqYWv6lNpjERdWG4QUZcWHjBR6JShnY2dhnLXne8muUYOXjhmopTlKMq5oy2xBRpS4aABlV6TVbENPV-pkRZjBWSlOXtc8nUZYRWWKWRXljUa6k0VN-4MRWVVgdF3ocdBdn8Yeq1hKhG1iTGW32YeXWZY+7mHWIn7jQuk0hdpQFXXNrGGYtu44Txj0rc1lnJW1SN9l9T0DrtjAKQDylA8VIPUUWdEQ1DkX6bVcOcSZ2PNuJL3rejXEM+lBF4z1BOeUTqkk3QAVC8LRwFuCIAuMgcBQFA+i8Jp00Q4x+gANoALpRCrAMKxdOnOkiXikTrFWrgbB06zNptiIbr4W5d+vW+b530YBytm9rzsUw7av0ko4uS9LUBlPLnv22AZTq5rHshQ6V3u0b50m+F8e287K7J470d0WHZQp2VWk53nFte+HSI+0AA)

**Question**

Due to the way type variance is handled in TS - contra-variant function arguments, but bi-variant method arguments - **is it possible to prevent (by raising a compiler error) `execute` being implemented as a method?**

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea if it's possible or not but I'm interested to know *why* you want to do this.

Comment: BTW, the latest typescript version (4.5.2) seems to refuse the first implementation. [See the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5ryQHkwBpkB5APmQG8BYAKGUeQgA8IEBXSALmQApQABy69MASmQBeSqXoBfevQQAbOAGc1adAGFVGgIzJgAW0HKIxiOE0ZskWIgj41YKKADmJEB2MAjaJS0dPRMzGycPPxCIsgubiDuYrzeftBSlPoA3MjyinQq6jY6emoATEam5pbWWna4js6uHl4+-lCBeaGs7FwQAiDCYLxxHknIKW3UIaFMUBBgHFAgyFnTjHI5dArB+QD2IGq75gB0yrvufCAQAO5auoX6fGLH3RF9AEQwu7vvYmKZSn2hxOZwuV1uGHuGlKTxe4V6fE+31+-yAA)

Comment: @JuniorDussouillez sorry, i made a mistake in the example code and forgot to add a link to my example ts code. It should have been  `=` not `:` in `MyClass`. Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: The reason is that function arguments are contra-variant, where as method arguments are bi-variant. Which means that when comparing types using `extends` you get different results depending on which implementation is used.

Comment: What if you didn't use an `interface` and instead used an `abstract class` you need to extend instead of implement? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG642m)?  The compiler doesn't like when you implement an abstract function-valued-property via a method.  If that works for you I can write up an answer. If that doesn't suffice then I think the answer might be "no", unfortunately.

Comment: @jcalz i had a feeling this one might be a no, but thanks for the taking a look. Using an abstract class is an interesting solution, but wouldn't work in this instance